# How to handle TIdHTTPServer with TIdMultiPartFormDataStream

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, simplehttpserver

Hi i need help on how to retrieved the parameters and data using IdHttpServer from indy.

many of my application uses TIdMultiPartFormDataStream to send data over the php. I would like to use the TIdHTTPServer to verify parameters for some reason and forward the request to its destination.

i created a short example for you to see.

```
uses
  IdContext, IdMultipartFormData;

// Server Side------------------------------------------------

IdHTTPServer1.Defaultport := 88;
IdHTTPServer1.active := True;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  // the request will be pass through its destination by POST/GET
  // and send the result back to the client apps.
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := ARequestInfo.Params.Text;
end;

// Client Side------------------------------------------------
// This will work using the standard Post or Get
procedure TForm1.btnPost1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  res: String;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add('Param1=Data1');
    sl.Add('Param2=Data1');
    sl.Add('Param3=Data2');
    sl.Add('Param4=Data3');
    res := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost:88/some.php', sl);
    ShowMessage(res);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

//how can i get the parameters and value for this code in my IdHttpServer
procedure TForm1.btnPost2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mfd: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  res: String;
begin
  mfd := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    mfd.AddFormField('Param1', 'Data1');
    mfd.AddFormField('Param2', 'Data1');
    mfd.AddFormField('Param3', 'Data2');
    mfd.AddFormField('Param4', 'Data3');
    res := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost:88/some.php', mfd);
    ShowMessage(res);
  finally
    mfd.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and how would i know if the Client apps pass a TIdMultiPartFormDataStream type of parameter?

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked and answered many times before in the [Embarcadero](http://forums.embarcadero.com) and [Indy](http://forums2.atozed.com) forums.  Please search through their archives, as well as other archives, like [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com), to find code examples.

In a nutshell, when the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event is triggered, if the `AResponseInfo.ContentType` property says `multipart/form-data` (the version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` you are using will send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead), the `AResponseInfo.PostStream` property will contain the raw MIME data that the client posted.  You can use the `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` class to parse it.  However, that class was never intended to be used server-side, so it is not very intuitive to use, but it is possible nontheless.

In Indy 11, I am planning on implementing native `multipart/form-data` parsing directly into `TIdHTTPServer` itself, but there is no ETA on that yet as we have not started work on Indy 11 yet.